# Repeatedly adding digits of a number until the output has a single digit

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I have a two digits number (e.g. 29) ) and wish to further reduce it to a single digit. How can I do such in python? Shall I use the function inside the while loop ?
e.g.

```
29 -> 11 -> 2
```

result:
[29,11,2]

```
x=input('Input digit: ')

result=0

box=[]


def add_two(x):
    bz=[]
    for i in str(x):
        bz.append(int(i))
        s=sum(bz)
        
    return s


box=[]    
a=0

while len(str(x))>1:
```

Comment: You could simplify your question to remove the useless stuff (the birthday thing) and only keep the minimum ;)

Comment: I simplified the question

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to reduce a two digit number (29) into a single digit number by performing addition of the tens and units, repeatedly until the number is smaller than 10.

*NB. I am using **integers** here, if you start from a string, first convert to int: `x = int(x)`*

Let's use `divmod` by 10 to get the two components:

```
divmod(29, 10)
# 2, 9
```

and `sum` them:

```
sum(divmod(29, 10))
# 11
```

Now that we have the logic, let's repeat it:

```
x = 29
def reduce(x):
    return sum(divmod(x,10))

while x>9:
    x = reduce(x)
    
print(x)
# 2   # 2+9 -> 11 ; 1+1 -> 2
```

###### as a single function

```
def reduce_until(x):
    while x>9:
        x = sum(divmod(x,10))
    return x

reduce_until(29)
# 2
```

###### generic function for an input of any size:

```
def reduce_until(x):
    while x>9:
        total = 0
        while x>0:
            x,r = divmod(x, 10)
            total += r
        x = total
    return x

reduce_until(56789)
# 56789 -> 35 -> 8

reduce_until(99999999999992)
# 99999999999992 -> 119 -> 11 -> 2
```

Comment: cheers @mozway @nekomura! You both are legends

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

dob_d = 29
while not (0 <= dob_d <= 9):
    n = 0
    for i in range(math.ceil(math.log10(dob_d))):
        n += int(dob_d / (10 ** i) % 10)
    dob_d = n

print(dob_d)
```